# Is there a way of making raspi-config verbose?

Tags: camera, config.txt

I am wanting to configure a RaspberryPi without using the raspi-config gui. Is there a way to do this, or at least get raspi-config to spit out the commands its running.

If not, is there a list of the configuration files it changes so I can change them myself?

Comment: I don't think there is anything in raspi-config that you can't change yourself, but I doubt there is any raspi-config documentation about this, since all those things will have their own documentation.  If you want to ask about something in particular, then ask a separate specific question about that (e.g., "How do I change a user password?") and mention that you *don't* want to use raspi-config.

Comment: Alternatively, open up raspi-config script in a text editor and see for yourself which options do what.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as mentioned raspi-config is a text file so you can look inside and see what it's doing or edit it to log what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

`raspi-config` is a giant shell script.  You can open it up with a command like `less $(which raspi-config)`, or view it in the [official repo on github](https://github.com/asb/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config).  At the very bottom of the file, [around line 950](https://github.com/asb/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config#L950) is the main loop.  From there, scroll around to the respective `do_*()` function you're interested in.